# Can I query users by using lastLoginTime in query in Google Admin sdk?

Tags: google-api, google-admin-sdk

In my organization , we want to filter users who has not logged in for last 30 days.

Can I use query=lastLoginTime<2022-03-15 in google admin sdk api.

I am using this api https://admin.googleapis.com/admin/directory/v1/users?query=lastLoginTime<2022-03-15

Or is there any other api which return the expected result.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am afraid it is not possible at the moment. This is the list of query parameters you can use with that method so far:

- name
- email
- givenName
- familyName
- isAdmin
- isDelegatedAdmin
- isSuspended
- im
- externalId
- manager
- managerId
- directManager
- directManagerId
- address
- addressPoBox
- addressExtended
- addressStreet
- addressLocality
- addressRegion
- addressPostalCode
- addressCountry
- orgName
- orgTitle
- orgDepartment
- orgDescription
- orgCostCenter
- phone
- orgUnitPath
- isEnrolledIn2Sv
- isEnforcedIn2Sv
- schemaName.fieldName

You can find additional info of each parameter in the official documentation [here](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/search-users).

In addition to that you can request this as a feature for this API [here](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/support#missing_features).

Comment: @TomCobo The answer seems to be "I am afraid it is not possible.". The links are for additional reference, as such this is not a "link-only answer".